# D3 Pie chart arc partitions

Tags: d3.js

I create a pie chart using D3 which looks similar to 
[image]

I need to draw white partitions between the arcs. Something like:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235.

I am unable to figure out which pare of code creates this partition. Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out, its the css

```
.arc path {
  stroke: #fff;
}
```